# rails skip after_find callback for particular method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I am using `after_find` callback to denormalize the phone after executing/selecting users table.

```
after_find :denormalize_phone

def denormalize_phone
  self.phone = "....."
end
```

I have a problem when I tried to create a dynamic method like below. I want to skip the `after_find` callback for this particular block. Can anyone help me?

```
User.order(:state).map(&:state).uniq.each do |state|
  define_singleton_method("is_#{state}_for") do |r|
    ....
  end
end
```

tx

Comment: What do you mean by 'denormalizing' phone ?
Maybe you should do the 'denormalization' when inserting, you can use a gem for this, https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer

Comment: Yeah, it's valid and fit for this.

Comment: Would you accept this if I post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use after_find for this. Seriously I can't find any reason to ever use after_find. Here are your options (ordered from best to worst IMO):

1. Use a decorator object for your User object. Decorators are used to group presentation logic of models. You could implement it yourself (not that hard) or here's a [gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) to get you started.
2. Use a helper method. Something like `format_phone(@user.phone)`. The downside is of course that you will have to call helper everywhere.
3. Overwrite `phone` method in your User model. To get database value of it you can use self[:phone]. This is a bit messy though since you're putting presentation logic in data layer.

Comment: It might be a wrong place to use `after_find`. But, it's very useful in the scenario; attach new dynamic property enabled=true/false with user object after each find. 
Your second point is valid one. But, @cthulhu's suggestion is very fit for this situation. Thx for ur comments.